# Getting class text with multiple spaces - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text in a class using BeautifulSoup but the class has multiple spaces. Converting to text, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. This makes me think i'm not actually getting the text for that class.

Here is the line i'm using to get the text. `ticket_count = soup.find('div', class_ = 'ui black circular label ticket-count')`

Is the issue the spaces in the class name?

Comment: This should be working if it's the exact value of the class attribute in the given element ([docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)). Can you provide some of the input html?

Comment: Update the `url` that you are trying to scrape and expected output

Comment: this is the class https://imgur.com/a/KivYEa4

Comment: the syntax looks correct, is the class name unique or does it have multiple occurrences on the web page? It would help if you can share the `url`.

Comment: I am not being able to reproduce the issue. Perhaps the element is dynamically generated (via javascript). If  that's the case you may be interested in something like [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Whole code with url: https://pastebin.com/njqrbyq3

Comment: The response body is mainly a javascript link and `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app buddy</noscript>`, so you I think you will need to run the javascript to get the data you want.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to know when a ticket becomes available. The web-page uses JavaScript to poll a web-socket connection to see if tickets are available. The web-socket returns JSON. You can mimic the behavior by polling the web-socket with Python. The following code polls the web-socket every 5 seconds until a ticket becomes available an then prints the JSON object detailing the available ticket. (You will need to install websocket if you have not done so already.)

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection
import time


def run():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(5)
        ws = create_connection("wss://mothership.splendourtickets.com/stream")
        r = ws.recv()
        ws.close()
        for t in json.loads(r)['tickets']:
            if not t['ticketCount'] == 0:
                return (t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ticket = run()
    print (json.dumps(ticket, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Outputs when a ticket becomes available:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Three Day Ticket",
    "ticketCount": 1,
    "ticketCountStr": "1",
    "type": "eventTicket"
}
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou so much! That's exactly what I was looking for.